# How to add the string "Figure" and the figure number to the subfigure caption

Tags: captions, subcaption

I have a long document and want to change the behaviour of the `subfigure` captions (from `subcaption` package) in just one figure.

A multi-page figure with a single `subfigure` on each page (see MWE below) produces  `(a) description of sub figure 1a` on page 1, `(b) description of sub figure 1b` on page 2 and

```
(c) description of sub figure 1c
Figure 1: Full description of figure
```

on page 3. What I want is a subfigure caption of the form

```
Figure 1(a): description of sub figure 1a
```

on each page, obviously with the `(a)` replaced accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
            \caption{description of sub figure \ref{label1a}}
            \label{label1a}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    \clearpage
    \begin{figure}
        \ContinuedFloat
        \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
            \caption{description of sub figure \ref{label1b}}
            \label{label1b}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    \clearpage
    \begin{figure}
        \ContinuedFloat
        \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
            \caption{description of sub figure \ref{label1c}}
            \label{label1c}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Full description of figure \ref{label1}}
        \label{label1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Completely rewrote the answer after receiving a comment from the OP)

I propose to set up a new caption-writing macro -- called `\newsubcap` in the code below -- that formats the captions of subfigures the way you've laid it out in your posting. The advantage of using a custom captioning command is that there's no need to redefine macros such as `\subfigurename` and to have to remember to reset these macros to their defaults at the end of the `figure` environment in question.

The `\newsubcap` macro is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand\newsubcap[1]{\phantomcaption%
       \caption*{\figurename~\thefigure(\thesubfigure): #1}}
```

You are obviously free to choose a different, catchier name.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\newcommand\newsubcap[1]{\phantomcaption%
       \caption*{\figurename~\thefigure(\thesubfigure): #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
   \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
      \newsubcap{Description of sub figure \thefigure\thesubfigure}
      \label{label1a}
   \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
   \ContinuedFloat
   \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
      \newsubcap{Description of sub figure \thefigure\thesubfigure}
      \label{label1b}
   \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
   \ContinuedFloat
   \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
      \newsubcap{Description of sub figure \thefigure\thesubfigure}
      \label{label1c}
   \end{subfigure}

\caption{Full description of figure \ref{label1}}
\label{label1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That got me `Figure (a)` etc, so I added a `\ref` to the main caption label and now get `Figure 1(a)` using `\renewcommand\subfigurename{Figure \ref{label1}:}`

Comment: @cdmh - I've updated and rewritten my answer completely to address the concern mentioned in your follow-up comment.

Comment: @Mico. Many thanks for the answer! Is it possible to change the `\newcommand\newsubcap[1]` such that it displays`Figure 1(a): Description of sub` instead of `Figure 1(a): Description of sub 1a` (without repeaiting the name of the subfigure at the end of the caption?

Comment: @Mico. Sorry indeed. I looked at the definition of newsubcap but didn't change the inside of the caption itself. It works perfectly. You can forget my previous comment